# Find a parametric representation for an ellipsoid

Tags: calculus

I am trying to find a parameteriztion for  $x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 = 4 $ that lies to the right of y=0. So far, I am thinking I can use $x = \cos{\theta}, y = \sin{\theta}$ and $ z=z$ I am thinking that $dV = dzdrd\theta$ But, I am unsure about what happens to the 4. I have to set up an integral in my parameterization.

Comment: Quite a few problems here. Go back and look at spherical polar coordinates as well as the Jacobian and what it is for spherical polars.

Comment: So you are saying that spherical coordinates are more adequate? We have not learned the Jacobian.

Comment: With your parametrization $x^2+y^2=1$, which is certainly not the case.

Answer (score 1):

$$
x = r \cos t \\
z = \frac{r}{\sqrt{2}} \cos t \\
y = \sqrt{4 - x^2 - 2z^2} 
= \sqrt{4 - r^2} 
$$

$r$ in the range $[0, 1]$, $t \in [0, 2\pi)$.

I leave you to take the derivatives and find the appropriate volume element.